# Tippy.js - Unable to hide a tooltip using the tippy.js documentation function

Tags: javascript, tooltip

I'm using [tippy.js](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/) for tooltips on a website, but it comes to a point when I have to hide them manually with a function (on mobile). However I'm unable to hide it using the built in function `hide()`

Am I doing something wrong or is the library bugged?

Here's the [documentation](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/#controlling-tooltips-manually) showing the hide() function.
And here's a snippet of my problem.

```js
var instance = new Tippy('button')

var i = 0;

$(document).on('keyup', function() {
  $('.clickcount').html(i);
  i++;

  var popper = instance.getPopperElement(document.querySelector('.tippy-popper'));
  instance.hide(popper)

})
```

```css
button {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/tippy/tippy.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/tippy/tippy.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<button title="text">Button with Tippy</button>

<div class="clickcount">Focus the document, then hover the button and press any key to hide it.</div>
```

Any and all help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/#controlling-tooltips-manually):

> Find the element's popper reference by calling the method `getPopperElement` and passing in the element directly:

You need to pass your element to `getPopperElement`, not the popup.

```js
var instance = new Tippy('button')

var i = 0;

$(document).on('keyup', function() {
  $('.clickcount').html(i);
  i++;

  var popper = instance.getPopperElement(document.querySelector('button'));
  instance.hide(popper)

})
```

```css
button {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/tippy/tippy.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/tippy/tippy.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<button title="text">Button with Tippy</button>

<div class="clickcount">Focus the document, then hover the button and press any key to hide it.</div>
```

Comment: you realize this does not work if you have hundreds of tooltips right ?

Comment: @Jaxx0rr it is a 6 years old answer to a specific situation provided by OP. The latest version of tippy has a [`hideAll`](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/methods/#hideall) method for general use if you are looking for a way to hide all tooltips in a document.